# Extracting the memo from the transaction record

Tags: transactions, stellar-laboratory, memo

Stellar newbie here, using the ZuluCrypto PHP SDK. I can successfully submit this transaction:

```php
$transaction = Server::testNet()
    ->buildTransaction(xxx_Account_A_xxx)
    ->addCustomAssetPaymentOp($asset, $amount, xxx_Account_B_xxx)
    ->setMemo( new Memo(3, 'DEADMEATDEADMEATDEADMEATDEADMEAT'));
```

(`3` is the `MEMO_TYPE` for a 32 byte hash.) But then transaction record retrieved from `horizon-testnet` shows the memo as `REVBRE1FQVRERUFETUVBVERFQURNRUFUREVBRE1FQVQ=` (with the correct `memo_type` 3), and the Stellar Lab XDR viewer won't decode this as a "Memo" or anything else.

How do I set a memo and then retrieve that memo from the transaction record?

Answer (score 2):

The memo value returned by Horizon is base64 encoded. You can decode the value with [`base64_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php).

Comment: Where in the account->transactions is the memo?